# Chrome issues with Roaming Profiles: Not shutting down propely

Tags: windows-7, group-policy, google-chrome

Has anyone ran into similar issues and have been able to work it out ? Many of our roaming profile users ran into the following:

1. When logging in, they have to open task manager and close chrome before starting it.
2. Bookmarks, etc, aren't saved after log off even when logged into the same computer.
3. I have tried changing Chrome's GPO settings to redirect chrome folders, but it did not seem to help, and in fact more users had to use task manager to close Chrome.

Comment: As for numbers 1 and 3 I have no idea. As for number 2, if the users have a Google account then they can log into Chrome and then their bookmarks, settings, etc. will be saved across sessions and across computers.

Comment: @joeqwerty: That's what I've done so far, but like you said, it doesn't solve the rest, and there's a good chance they're all related.